# Tryng to programm 27C256 chip in proteus

Tags: simulation, proteus

I've made a simple circuit in Proteus with 27C256 chip.
I have 4 variables or input (A, B, C, D). I have 8 functions to implement.
I wrote mi functions in a text file and saved it with the extension (.bin)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/WPDD0.jpg

After I edit properties on the chip and load the saved bin file and run the simulation all works well except that it doesn't do what it suppose to do.
I do not know how to write mi functions in the text file so the Proteus simulation works.
I never done this before and i have to make this as a project for college.

Can someone help me with how am i suppose to write mi functions in the text file so when I run the simulation it does what it is intended to do?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The file name extension already gives it away: Your software expects the contents of the ROM in raw binary format. It just takes whatever you wrote in that "bin" file and dumps it right into the ROM without any kind of conversion. If you tell it to load a file containing text, you will get a ROM that contains text - and not the binary functions you wanted.

You will most likely have to create the file using a hex editor. The file should only be 16 bytes large (since 4 binary inputs can produce 16 different combinations).